# How to globally left align the text of paragraphs containing variable-length headers with the first line of the paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, sections-paragraphs

I have several `paragraph`s each with unique headers of differing lengths:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\paragraph{Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\paragraph{Long Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\paragraph{Long Long Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\end{document}
```

I'm looking for a global setting which will variably format each paragraph's text such as (disregarding the '...'):

> **Subsection 1**
>
> **Title** Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.
>   ........Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.
>
> **Subsection 2**
>
> **Long Title** Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text
>   .................here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph
>   .................text here.
>
> **Long Long Title** Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph
>   ..........................text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.
>   ..........................Paragraph text here.

I'm sure there's a `enumitem` solution, however I want to stick with using `paragraph`s and stay away from `enumitem` workarounds. I believe some usage of `\hangindent` and/or `\hangafter` might work, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: I thing what you need is a description list.

Comment: @HarishKumar Like I said, I want to stick with using `paragraph`s and stay away from `enumitem`, or any sort of listing, workarounds.

Comment: `\paragraph` is the wrong markup here, that is a _fourth_ level heading after section,subsection,subsubsection  You are missing level three headings (which will show up if you increase secnumdepth or tocdepth so the section hierarchy is used in full)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I realize. I didn't include the higher levels for the sake of the min. example.

Comment: OK:-) (it was worth mentioning as `\paragraph` is one of the more misunderstood latex commands:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\myparagraph` like this:

```
\usepackage{calc}  %% provides `\widthof` macro
\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[2][]{%
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{\textbf{#2}}}
\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\mylen+1em\relax}
\paragraph[#1]{#2}
\hangindent=\mylength
}
```

And then use `\myparagraph{Title}` whenever you want hanging.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[2][]{%
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{\textbf{#2}}}
\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\mylen+1em\relax}
\paragraph[#1]{#2}
\hangindent=\mylength
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\myparagraph{Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\myparagraph{Long Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\myparagraph{Long Long Title}
Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here. Paragraph text here.

\end{document}
```

[image]